# Chances of getting mono from beer pong?

Tags: statistics

In a friendly game of Beer pong there is 1 cup that has been previously used by a person with mono. Assuming the cup is infected what are the chances that you drink the infected cup if you drink 4 cups out of the 10 in the cups triangle?

In beer pong, your partner drinks 1 cup followed by you drinking one and so on. In this game you both drink till one cup is left. That last cup is thrown out.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: No symptoms yet. So I'm not sure. Isn't it 1/10 + 1/9 + 1/8 + 1/7?

Comment: Well, what would your chances be if the infected cup were the first one? The second one?

Comment: 1/10 + 1/9 + 1/8 + 1/7?

Comment: How about this - imagine 1000 triangles of 10 cups. A thousand people do what you did, drinking 4 of the 10 cups in the triangles. If there is a single mono cup in each triangle, how many of the 1000 people do you expect to have drunk the mono cup?

Comment: hmm 400 people? so 40 percent chance?

Comment: Good job - you got it. Your partner has a 50 percent chance (assuming he drank 5 cups), and there is a 10 percent chance that the cup that was thrown out was the mono cup.

Answer (score 0):

You picked 4 cups, each with a 10 percent chance of being the mono cup. Your chance is 40%.